# VBA Colorize text in "row list"

Tags: vba, excel

is there a way to give a serten word in a drop-down list color? I have managend so that the code can set color to the background but not to the text without an error message.

```
' Create a cell with drop down menu and color formatting, this is specifide for a cell
Sub CreateRequirementAcceptanceDropDownCell(CurrentCell As Range)
'
' CreateDataValidationCell Macro
'
    Dim dvLists(1 To 4) As String 'data validation area
    dvLists(1) = "Accepted"
    dvLists(2) = "Accepted with Deviation"
    dvLists(3) = "Not Accepted"
    dvLists(4) = "Not Confirmed"

    CurrentCell.Select

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(dvLists, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    ' Colour background, but can´t colour text....
    ColorizeStatus
    Selection.Value = "Not Confirmed"
End Sub


Sub ColorizeStatusText(ColorRange As Range)
    ColorRange.Select
    '------------ Applicable ----
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""Not Accepted"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255 ' red
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    '---------------------------------------------------
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

This is my functions. It works when i want to add color to the background, (this function gives the word `"Not Accepted"` a red background). But my goal is to change the word `Not Accepted` to red and not change background. I tried using `.Font.Color` in different scenarios but none worked... Is there a way to change the text color in this function? Thanks

Comment: you have .interior in the With statement, so that will change the interior color.  You need a separate statement for just changing the font color.

Comment: .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)---
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm---
This might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in comments above:

```
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
         .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' red
        .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: bytheway, leave .select and selection out : With ColorRange.FormatConditions(1).Font